# Shiny app turns grey (Disconnected from the server) when deployed, works fine locally

Tags: r, shiny

I deployed an application
This is my application: https://jleandroj.shinyapps.io/indicators/
this is the repository: https://github.com/jleandroj/indicators

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(raster)
library(sp)
shinyUI(navbarPage("Global indicators",
tabPanel("Main indicators",
fluidPage(  
  imageOutput("distPlot",width = "100%",height = "400px"),
    hr(),
    fluidRow(
    column(9,
      h4("Ranking"),     
      dataTableOutput('table')
    ),  
    column(3,
    br(),
    checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Social and economic   indicators"), 
                choices = list('Breast cancer per 100th' = 'breastcancerper100th', 'HIV rate' = 'hivrate',
                                                                   'Suicide per 100th' = 'suicideper100th',
                                                                   'Oil per person' = 'oilperperson',
                                                                   'Alc consumption' = 'alcconsumption',
                                                                   'Polity score' = 'polityscore',
                                                                   'Armed forces rate' = 'armedforcesrate',
                                                                   'CO2 emissions' = 'co2emissions',
                                                                   'Income per person' = 'incomeperperson',
                                                                   'Female employ rate' = 'femaleemployrate',
                                                                   'Employ rate' = 'employrate',
                                                                   'Internet use rate' = 'internetuserate',
                                                                   'Electric per person' = 'relectricperperson'),selected = 'breastcancerper100th')
              )))
    ),
    tabPanel("About indicators",
             includeMarkdown("read.Rmd")
             )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(raster)
polygons <- shapefile("data/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")
gap<-read.csv("data/gapminder.csv",header = TRUE)
names(gap)[1]<-paste("NAME")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

polygons1 <- merge(polygons,gap, by="NAME")

spplot(polygons1,input$checkGroup, main=paste(input$checkGroup), lwd=.8, col="black")

})

output$table <-  renderDataTable({ 

  gap2<-subset(gap, select = c("NAME",input$checkGroup));

  gap2<-gap2[with(gap2, order(-gap2[,2])),];

  gap2
})
})
```

When I deployed I get a gray screen with a message "Disconnected from the server"

I have modified many options in settings and I added many libraries, I tried all But I got the same message.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the path to the csv file

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. I have tried to set up in other ways, but I did not get. I changed header by row.names. Could you give me some clue as I can do better. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi rmaddy. I have already solved my problem. I looked on logs. This part showed me the errors. There was not a library rgdal.

Comment: Having the same problem. So the reason for the error was that you're importing libraries not available?